# Read a matrix from a text file and print it

Tags: arrays, matrix, fortran, fortran90

I want to write an 3 x 4 matrix from a 12 line txt numerical file
I have written a Fortran 90 program for the same

```
program array
  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: I4B = selected_int_kind(4)
  integer (I4B), allocatable, dimension (:,:) :: arr
  integer (I4B) :: i

  open(unit=99, file='1.txt')
  open(unit=100, file='out.txt')

  Allocate (arr(3,4))

  do i=1, 12
    read(99,*)arr(3,4)
    write(100,*),arr(3,4)
  enddo

  close (99)

  deAllocate (arr)

  stop
endprogram array
```

but it's giving an error

```
At line 10 of file array.f90 (unit = 99, file = '1.txt')
Fortran runtime error: End of file
```

Line number 10 is `read(99,*)arr(3,4)`.

Comment: Please show us some code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have no idea how to index an array and call it

Comment: In that case you should read some tutorial or textbook. Asking for a full totorial here is too broad and therefore off-topic. Also please take some care when writing your post, do use capital letters when beginning a sentence, even a non-native beginner in English can do that.

Comment: i have changed the question. please have a look at it

Comment: Please check that I identified the correct line number 10 when improving your formatting. You should also supply the input file content.

Comment: It is very strange, that you crash with an end of file because you are just reading 12 numbers always to the same element of the array (`arr(3,4)`). Are you sure the file exists and is not empty? I recommend `open(unit=99, file='1.txt', status='old', action='read')`

Comment: yes line number 10 is correct. input file is numbers from 1 to 12 written on separate lines

Comment: same error is occuring @VladimirF

Comment: the output is coming the same way as input. i want it

Comment: Did you check the content of the file? Is it not empty? Post the content here. Be sure you are in the right directory (folder). No it is not the correct way, you will need two loops. Reading of `arr(3,4)` is wrong. But that is a different problem.

Comment: With list-directed input, just do `read(99,*) arr` and that will read all 12 numbers regardless of how many records they are split over.  Not that that will solve a problem with the layout of the file.

Comment: yes i have checked the input file. ok i will try using two loops. and now it will have 3 rows and 4 columns and i want to sort first element of each column in ascending order(if at all the input contents are not sorted) and the elements below the first elements of that column sholud also get shifted according to the first element order. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: how to apply the two loops in order to get a 3 x 4 matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very simple implementation of your array. It uses the fact that the first index is the fastest changing. So I just keep reading until all 12 elements of the array are filled.

Then, for output, I specify a format that it should write 3 values per line.

```
program readfile
    implicit none
    integer, dimension(:, :), allocatable :: arr
    open(unit=99, file='1.txt', action='READ', status='OLD')
    open(unit=100, file='out.txt', action='WRITE', status='NEW')
    allocate(arr(3, 4))
    read(99, *) arr
    write(100, '(3I4)') arr
    close(99)
    close(100)
end program readfile
```

If you want to do it explicitly, you have to calculate the two indices independently for each value read:

```
program readfile
    implicit none
    integer, dimension(:, :), allocatable :: arr
    integer :: i, row, col
    open(unit=99, file='1.txt', action='READ', status='OLD')
    open(unit=100, file='out.txt', action='WRITE', status='NEW')
    allocate(arr(3, 4))

    ! Read the elements:
    do i = 1, 12
        row = mod(i-1, 3)+1
        col = (i-1) / 3 + 1
        read(99, *) arr(row, col)
    end do

    ! write the elements:
    do i = 1, 4
        write(100, '(3I4)') arr(:, i)
    end do
    close(99)
    close(100)
end program readfile
```

By the way, your code:

```
do i = 1, 12
    read(99, *) arr(3, 4)
    write(100, *) arr(3, 4)
end do
```

would just 12 times read a single number from the input file, store it in the last location of the array, then write that same number back to the output file.

Also, your error message suggests that you have tried to read past the end of the file. Either your `1.txt` doesn't contain 12 lines, or you might have read something else first, for example to find out how many elements there are. In that case, you would need to add a `rewind(99)` before you start reading the actual numbers.